# PHP - Multiple file upload stuck at 20 items

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to setup a multiple image uploader and whenever I try and upload more than 20 files, only the first 20 files are uploaded.

Before I continue, id just like to say that max_file_uploads in php.ini is setup to 400, so other answers to very similar questions do not seem to resolve my problem.

My full code is below, please note I know I am using mysql_query, but this is just for local testing purposes.

-

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    include("SimpleImage.php");

    echo count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]));

        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        $date = date_create();

        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 10485760)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
            $name = date_timestamp_get($date) . "_" . mt_rand() . "." . $extension;

            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$key] > 0){
                $messages[] = "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] . "<br>";
            }else{
                $imagethumbTrueLocation = "../../gallery/thumb/" . $name;
                $imagelargeTrueLocation = "../../gallery/photos/" . $name;

                $imagethumb = new SimpleImage();
                $imagethumb->load($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
                $imagethumb->resizeToWidth(230);
                $imagethumb->save($imagethumbTrueLocation);

                $imagethumblocation = "thumb/" . $name;

                $imagelarge = new SimpleImage();
                $imagelarge->load($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
                $imagelarge->resizeToWidth(800);
                $imagelarge->save($imagelargeTrueLocation);

                $imagelargelocation = "photos/" . $name;

                $queryresult = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gallery (thumbnail, highres) VALUES ('$imagethumblocation', '$imagelargelocation')") or die(mysql_error());
                if(!$queryresult) {
                    $messages[] = "Failed to insert record into the database.";
                }else{
                    $messages[] = "Record sucessfully added to the database.";
                }
            }
        }else{
            $messages[] = "Invalid file";
        }
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: How about `post_max_size`?

Comment: HI @Jon post_max_size is 64M. The 47 images I am trying to upload are  4.5MB in total.

Comment: Hi Oliver, I've wrote a piece of code very similar of yours (using SimpleImage class) and I have almost the same problem. The upload can be stuck and nothing happens, the browser's trying to do something but I can't figure why it doesn't work. No timeout. No error... just the loading icon spinning. Did you found a solution to your problem? It could help me to investigate...

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned the max_file_uploads but could it be the case that 400 isnt recognised try 99? The only reason I say this is its a specific number 20! every time there must be a limit. Also have you checked apache config there may be a limit in there as well

I would personally fire these off with javascript so each upload has their own thread so to speak and you would be able to work round the limit if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my host has set their own limit on this which means only VPS and Dedicated accounts can change this value :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wamp, go on localhost page, and click on phpinfo(); in the left bottom corner.
If not you can use the function in a php file.

you will see : "Loaded Configuration File" column, to find your php.ini

Because there are multiple php.ini (one in php folder and the other in apach folder).
When done, you can verify it in phpinfo() again, just CTRL + F and look for "max_file_uploads".

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Open the php.ini configuration file and change the 
;Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
**max_file_uploads =**
to the number of files you want apache to handle on POST events.
The default value is 20.